# Java serializing proto into JSON

Tags: java, spring, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to seriealize a class containing proto back into a json response
That's how I create the Class from a yaml file:

```
for (String yamlString : strings) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            try {
                AbilityWrapper ability = mapper.readValue(yamlString, PredefinedRuleWrapper.class);
                if (ability.isActive()) {
                    abilities.add(ability);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Class definition:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AbilityWrapper {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = AbilityProtoDeserializer.class)
    private Model.Ability ability;
    private boolean active;

    public static class AbilityProtoDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Model.Ability> {
        @Override
        public Model.Ability deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            Model.Builder builder = Model.Ability.newBuilder();
            JsonFormat.parser().merge(p.readValueAsTree().toString(), builder);
            return builder.build();
        }
    }

}
```

When debugging the proto is correctly saved, but when I try to return the HTTP response I get:

```
handleException
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->abilities.ability.AbilityWrapper["rule"]->abilities.Model$AbilityDto["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])
```

When trying to add a serializer like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PredefinedRuleWrapper {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = AbilityProtoDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = PredefinedRuleWrapperSerializer.class)
    private Rules.RuleDto rule;
.
.
.
    public static class AbilityWrapperSerializer extends StdSerializer<AbilityWrapper> {
        public AbilityWrapperSerializer() {
            super(AbilityWrapper.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(AbilityWrapper value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
            node.put("active", value.isActive());

            // Convert the RuleDto to JSON string using protobuf's JsonFormat
            String ruleJson = JsonFormat.printer().print(value.getAbility());
            JsonNode abilityNode = mapper.readTree(AbilityJson);
            node.set("ability", abilityNode);

            mapper.writeValue(gen, node);
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following error: (not sure if it's a progress or not, and for some reason when debugging the code doesn't even get to the serializer)

```
 Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: class.Message$AbilityDto cannot be cast to class.AbilityWrapper (Abilities$abilityDto and AbilityWrapper are in unnamed module of loader 'app'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class Abilities$abilityDto cannot be cast to class .abilities.AbilityWrapper (Abilities$abilityDto and abilities.AbilityWrapper are in unnamed module of loader 'app') (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->ability.AbilityWrapper["ability"])]
```